# get count on every date and make date values as column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table with values;

```
CUSTOMER_ID CUST_TYPE   REG_DATE
1706021001  GENERAL     2017-06-02 
1706021002  GENERAL     2017-06-02 
1707091001  GENERAL     2017-07-09 
1707091002  GENERAL     2017-07-09  
1707111001  STAFF       2017-07-11 
1707111002  STUDENT     2017-07-14 
1706021003  GENERAL     2017-07-14
```

I've wrote the query for getting the count of CUST_TYPE, but how to show REG_DATE value as column.

```
SELECT [REG_DATE]
    ,[CUST_TYPE]
    ,COUNT(CUST_TYPE) [COUNT]
FROM [dbo].[tbl_new_customer_registration]
WHERE a.REG_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2017-06-02', 112))
    AND a.REG_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2017-07-11', 112))
GROUP BY CUST_TYPE,REG_DATE;
```

I want to get the count of CUST_TYPE on every REG_DATE but the values of REG_DATE should appear as column. *Required output is*;

```
CUST_TYPE       2017-06-02  2017-07-09  2017-07-11  2017-07-14
GENERAL             2           2                       1
STAFF                                       1
STUDENT                                                 1
```

How can I get this output? Please help.

Guys I got the solution using help from the solutions provided, but I've one problem. The order of the Date columns are not in fixed order, I want to render the date columns in ascending order. I tried using ORDER BY clause, but every solution I tried shows error. **How can I order my result pivoted table in ascending order of Date column**?

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @p_from_dt DATE = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2017-06-02', 112));
DECLARE @p_to_dt DATE = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2017-07-14', 112));

SELECT @columns = ISNULL(@columns + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(status_date)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT convert(VARCHAR(10), REG_DATE, 120) [status_date]
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_new_customer_registration] a
    WHERE a.REG_DATE >= @p_from_dt
        AND a.REG_DATE <= @p_to_dt
    ) AS TheDays

SET @query = N' select * from
        (SELECT a.REG_DATE [REG_DATE]
        ,a.CUST_TYPE [CUST_TYPE]
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_new_customer_registration] a
    GROUP BY a.REG_DATE,a.CUST_TYPE 
    ) a
pivot(COUNT(CUST_TYPE) FOR [REG_DATE] IN (' + @columns + ')) p 
        '

--print @columns
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
GO
```

Comment: Google : Dynamic Pivot in Sql Server

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot and get this results as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select Customer_id, Cust_type, Reg_date from #customer ) a
    pivot (count(customer_id) for reg_date in ([2017-06-02],[2017-07-09],[2017-07-11],[2017-07-14])) p
```

Output as below:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Cust_type | 2017-06-02 | 2017-07-09 | 2017-07-11 | 2017-07-14 |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| GENERAL   |          2 |          2 |          0 |          1 |
| STAFF     |          0 |          0 |          1 |          0 |
| STUDENT   |          0 |          0 |          0 |          1 |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

For dynamic list of columns you can query as below:

```
declare @cols1 varchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)

select @cols1 = stuff((select distinct ','+QuoteName(Reg_date) from #customer  for xml path('')),1,1,'')
Declare @p_from_dt date = '2017-06-02'
Declare @p_to_dt date = '2017-07-14'

Select @query = '   Select * from (
        Select Customer_id, Cust_type, Reg_date from #customer 
            Where Reg_date between @p_from_dt and @p_to_dt ) a
        pivot (count(customer_id) for reg_date in ('+ @cols1 + ')) p '

--Select @query --Check for generated query 
exec sp_executesql @query, N'@p_from_dt date, @p_to_dt date', @p_from_dt, @p_to_dt
```

Change your columns column generation as below to get in order by Reg_date

```
Select @cols1 = stuff((select ','+QuoteName(Reg_date) from #customer group by Reg_Date order by Reg_date  for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```

Comment: Please can you explain why you have used `for xml path('')),1,1,'')`?

Comment: To get the comma separated distinct column names from Reg_Date.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Should this query take WHERE condition or not `WHERE REG_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @p_from_dt, 112))
  AND REG_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @p_to_dt, 112))` since my query is dynamic.

Comment: Yep you need to provide this condition in subquery

Comment: Please can you modify your query. That will be a great help. Thank You!!!

Comment: There are many ways to pass parameters to dynamic queries, one way is to use as parameters, accordingly updated the answer

Comment: I've provided the solution in the question but the problem is I can't use ORDER BY. How can I use ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Updated my answer to include order by on Reg_Date

Comment: Remove DISTINCT and do GROUP BY to do order by